# Android Google Maps, how can I add an icon or animation at onMapLongClick event?

Tags: android, google-maps, events, marker

I want to add an icon (or marker or image) at onMapLongClick event. The problem is that the icon will be shown only the few seconds while the user is touching the screen because I need to back to previous screen when the event is released. I have this code:

```
public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
    Intent mapa = new Intent();
    mapa.putExtra("lat", String.valueOf(point.latitude));
    mapa.putExtra("long", String.valueOf(point.longitude));
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, mapa);
    finish();
}
```

It works great, but I would like to add a marker or icon so the user knows where he is touching, only for aesthetic reasons =)

I have tried onMapClick event, but it is not released until the user remove the finger from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

All that you need is to add a **balloon overlay** on the exact point where the user clicks on the map.

Refer the below link which provides you the exact answer.

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons